# Second footcite isn't displayed correct

Tags: biblatex

If I use a same footcite twice, it isn't displayed in the correct form. Beside of that, I would like to count the footcites/notes not per page, but for the hole document. So, the cites of the second chapter has to be number 3 and 4.
Below my MWE which shows the problem.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,dutch]{report}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[scaled=.90]{helvet}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,citestyle=verbose-ibid,bibstyle=numeric,sorting=nyt]{biblatex}
\renewcommand{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\addspace}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{guardian1,
  author = {The Guardian},
  title = {Cyprus banks remain closed to prevent run on deposits},
  url = "http://www.theguardian.com/world/2013/mar/26/cyprus-banks-closed-prevent-run-deposits",
  urldate = "2014-11-15"
}
@misc{shrem3,
  author = "Shrem, Charlie",
  title = "",
  month = jan,
  year = "2014",
  howpublished = "Webwinkel Vakdagen"
  }
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchbibmacro{url+urldate}
  {\usebibmacro{urldate}}
  {\ifcitation{}{\usebibmacro{urldate}}}
  {}
  {}
\begin{document}


\chapter{Title}
Text and footcite\footcite[][]{guardian1} \footcite[][]{shrem3}

\chapter{Title2}
Text and footcite\footcite[][]{guardian1} \footcite[][]{shrem3}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What do you mean by “not in correct form”?

Comment: @egreg Not the whole footcite is shown at the second cite. I would recommend to try the MWE, I don't know for sure how to explain it.

Comment: Well, that's what `biblatex` considers correct: once a book/paper has been cited, the full form is not necessary any more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command `\footcite` generates footnotes which are treated as other footnotes are.

And in the `report` class the numbering of *all* footnotes is reset when a new chapter starts.

So, if you really want the behavior you've described in your request you can add the following lines in your preamble:

```
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{footnote}{chapter}
```

so that the `footnote` counter is not reset at each chapter, but note that *all* footnotes will follow this rule.

In regards of the issue in the title, I assume you want to display *always* the complete citation in the footnote. This can be achieved by using `\footfullcite` instead of `\footcite`, or adding the line

```
\let\footcite\footfullcite
```

so, each time you use `\footcite` you are using `\footfullcite`.

Complete MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,dutch]{report}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[scaled=.90]{helvet}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,citestyle=verbose,bibstyle=numeric,sorting=nyt,citereset=none]{biblatex}
\renewcommand{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\addspace}
\let\footcite\footfullcite

\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{footnote}{chapter}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{guardian1,
  author = {The Guardian},
  title = {Cyprus banks remain closed to prevent run on deposits},
  url = "http://www.theguardian.com/world/2013/mar/26/cyprus-banks-closed-prevent-run-deposits",
  urldate = "2014-11-15"
}
@misc{shrem3,
  author = "Shrem, Charlie",
  title = "",
  month = jan,
  year = "2014",
  howpublished = "Webwinkel Vakdagen"
  }
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchbibmacro{url+urldate}
  {\usebibmacro{urldate}}
  {\ifcitation{}{\usebibmacro{urldate}}}
  {}
  {}

\begin{document}


\chapter{Title}
Text and footcite\footcite[][]{guardian1} \footcite[][]{shrem3}

\chapter{Title2}
Text and footcite\footcite[][]{guardian1} \footcite[][]{shrem3}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is exactly what I asked for. Do you have another solution for the full cite that is referring with the title, footcitenumber and page to an earlier footcite (The Guardian, num. 1, blz. 1)?

Comment: @RemcoSwienink I'm sorry but I don't understand the request. Maybe it is better to ask a follow-up question...